# Results with empty values in parameter in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am creating a parameter for date to and from. Some dates in the record are missing, meaning there is null value. When my parameter searches between two values it avoid those results with empty date but I want to get those record also.

Sample code is,

```
AND TO_DATE(PLLA.PROMISED_DATE) 
    BETWEEN NVL (to_char(to_date(substr(:PROMISED_DATE_FROM, 1, 20), 'YYYY/MM/DD'), 'DD-MON-YY'), TO_DATE(PLLA.PROMISED_DATE)) 
        AND NVL (to_char(to_date(substr(:PROMISED_DATE_to, 1, 20), 'YYYY/MM/DD'), 'DD-MON-YY'), TO_DATE(PLLA.PROMISED_DATE))
```

Comment: Please add code and sample data.

Comment: AND TO_DATE(PLLA.PROMISED_DATE) BETWEEN NVL (to_char(to_date(substr(:PROMISED_DATE_FROM,1,20),'YYYY/MM/DD'),'DD-MON-YY'),TO_DATE(PLLA.PROMISED_DATE))
                                        and  NVL (to_char(to_date(substr(:PROMISED_DATE_to,1,20),'YYYY/MM/DD'),'DD-MON-YY'),TO_DATE(PLLA.PROMISED_DATE))

Comment: there are fields with emtpt values. when this parametre search between two dates. it avoids the whole record. but i want to get those record also

Comment: Please refer to my first comment above, thanks.

Comment: For future reference please **edit your question** to include clarifications or further information. In particular code is hard to read in comments because of the poor layout and formatting.

Comment: Also, is PLLA.PROMISED_DATE really not defined with a DATE datatype? Poor show.

Answer (score 0):

add nvl condition to PLLA.PROMISED_DATE as well... and try your code...

Comment: i did'nt get it. i just want to get idea that how do i deal with it.

Comment: if you use NVL(PLLA.PROMISED_DATE,sysdate) between :promised_from and :promised_to date- what will be the output?... try and update

Comment: @Tamil - *"if you use NVL(PLLA.PROMISED_DATE,sysdate) between :promised_from and :promised_to date- what will be the output?"* Hmmm, my bet is, a completely unreliable and almost certainly wrong result set. What do **you** think will happen?

Comment: @APC, i was just suggesting to use NVL on plla.promised date... not the exact command ... the developer has to do trial and testing on different scenarios to get desired output...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include records where PLLA.PROMISED_DATE is null then you simply need to include that criterion in the WHERE clause:

```
AND ( PLLA.PROMISED_DATE is null or 
      TO_DATE(PLLA.PROMISED_DATE) BETWEEN NVL (to_char(to_date(substr(:PROMISED_DATE_FROM,1,20),'YYYY/MM/DD'),'DD-MON-YY'),TO_DATE(PLLA.PROMISED_DATE)) 
                                  and NVL (to_char(to_date(substr(:PROMISED_DATE_to,1,20),'YYYY/MM/DD'),'DD-MON-YY'),TO_DATE(PLLA.PROMISED_DATE)) 
)
```

---

Your posted sample code is really hard to understand. Toggling of `to_char()` and `to_date()` is always a red flag. It would be better if :PROMISED_DATE_FROM and :PROMISED_DATE_TO were passed as actual dates. But if they are being passed as strings what is the need for `substr()`? And if the passed parameters do contain extraneous characters why isn't the substring 10 characters long, the length of the date mask you're using in the `to_date()`?

Also, why do you then flip the parameters back to strings when you're applying a `to_date()` to the PLLA.PROMISED_DATE? It would be a poor show if that column was not a date datatype but at the very least you need to ensure that you're comparing the same datatype on both sides of the `=` operator.